# correct html tag on localhost but sanitized in web even same php code and database

Tags: php, html, apache, codeigniter, web

I'm trying to figure out a strange issue I stumbled on:

Locally and on external server I use the same web environment thanks to Ansible and Vagrant.

I use Ubuntu, Apache Webserver, MySQL, PHP 7, Codeigniter 3.

On the edit form I see on localhost correct HTML tags.

[image: localhost]

But when I open the same page from the cloud (an external Webserver) the HTML tags are sanitized on Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

What's the cause of this behaviour and how can I prevent the sanitized html tags?

Comment: Try This one : use <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 insted of this place <meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: Are you sure the php config file is the same?

Comment: @JesseSchokker, yes, the php config file is the same.

Comment: @Arun, it doesn't fix the issue. still the same.

Comment: What happens when you wrap the string inside htmlentities()?

Comment: @JesseSchokker, then I get &amp;amp;lt;i&amp;amp;gt; 
with html_entity_decode I get &lt;i&gt;

Comment: If you look at the source of the page, what does it say there? Is it the same as on the actual page, or is the source different?

Comment: @JesseSchokker, the source is the same.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of your code. Are you using xss_clean() function? Also, did you take care to set a CI_ENV value on these machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't bothered to set CI_ENV correctly in either your configuration file application/config/config.php or via apache (either in .htaccess or apache conf) then you might get different behavior on the two different machines.

You should also check application/config/config.php for this value and see what it's set to:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Obviously, if you've bothered to define different config.php values in these locations, you may need to check them also:

```
application/config/development/config.php
application/config/testing/config.php
application/config/production/config.php
```

As a sanity check, you might want to define a controller method like this and see if it outputs different values on your respective machines:

```
public function ci_check() {
    echo CI_ENV;
}
```

If you find that the machines have different CI_ENV values, it may be that each machine is loading a different configuration file for config value **global_xss_filtering**. This might cause the problem you are seeing. Sort of hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: not necessary to check $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;